# Adding dll in another class? in Console applicatin?

Tags: c#-4.0

In C# console application, I created one calss and one method, and build the application. Then i created one more console application and i add reference of the the dll into the new class, but when i am trying to add the name space i am not getting the the calss.

```
namespace Mydll
{

    class Test
    {
        public int MUL(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            int z = t.MUL(10, 20);
            Console.WriteLine(z.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

when i am typing the namespace Mydll i am not able to get. Cna you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make the class

`public`: Public access is the most permissive access level

or

`internal` :Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly (if you are creating the console application in the same solution)

otherwise your class won't be visible

```
public class Test
    {
        public int MUL(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default accessibility of a class is 'internal' (if you don't define it). You must therefore define it as being public.

```
namespace Mydll
{

    public class Test
    {
        public int MUL(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            int z = t.MUL(10, 20);
            Console.WriteLine(z.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to this for more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28VS.80%29.aspx